# Sync data on android

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask, synchronization, getjson

Currently, I'm working on android app that displays reports from my local server with public IP address. I've already designed the web services (C#) to access the data from the SQL Server from my server. Besides, I've the app and sqlite database ready from the mobile side and the system works just fine with sample data I've already dumped on the sqlite. However, I want users to periodically (once in a week) update/sync data from my server using the webservice or any preferred method to the sqlite database on the mobile.

However, I've no clue as to how I should send/receive the latest data from the server and update the sqlite on the mobile side without disrupting users. Sometimes, user should also be able to check for updates themselves. I've read about JSON and Account Authentication but couldn't get the concept on how I can access my server (with public IP) and update the data.

What is the best way to handle my situation? Any reference or tutorial that can show me how to do the sync?

Thanks in advance

I tried this one but it crashes for some reason:

```
    public void syncClickHandler(View view) 
    {
        AsyncCallWS task=new AsyncCallWS();
        task.execute();
    }

private String response="";

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        response=Connect.Hello("TestName","Hello");
        if(response!=null)
            return response;
        return "Nothing returned!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

The class to access the webservice:

```
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:1674/Services.asmx";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/";

    public static String Hello(String name, String webMethName) 
{
    String resTxt = null;

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);

    PropertyInfo pi= new PropertyInfo();

    pi.setName("name");

    pi.setValue(name);

    pi.setType(String.class);

    request.addProperty(pi);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try 
    {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);

        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

        String n = "";

      Object property = response.getProperty(0); 
          if (property instanceof SoapObject) { 
            SoapObject countryObj = (SoapObject) property; 

            n=countryObj.getProperty("name").toString(); 
          } 

        resTxt=n;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        resTxt = "Error occured";
    } 

    return resTxt;
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: You might want to look at SyncAdapters here (pretty much every answer you're looking for): http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Answer (score 0):

Look friend, its quite simple; you can just make a sync button, the users will click the button. You consume the C# web services and put them into the local sqlite database of your device. When you receive a new set of data from the server, just delete the existing local table in your device and insert the newly acquired data from the web services. The response from the web services may be JSON or XML.

The request for the web sevices should be done using Async task.

Answer (score 0):

http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-403-webservice-access-tutorial.html

Hope this above link may helps you.